# How I can use 2 or more fields as primary_key in the grocery crud codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables: table1, table2, and table3.

- table1 has as primary to id_t1 ...;
- table2 has as primary to id_t1 and id_t2 ...,
- table3 has as primary to id_t1, id_t2, and id_t3...

How do I edit records to tables 2 and 3, with grocery crud that recognizes only one field as primary?

Comment: I don't know what a grocery codeingiter is, but you can have a multi-column primary key.

Comment: codeigniter is a framework:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter
and grocery crud is a library:
http://www.grocerycrud.com/